# Connect to RDF4J server with Sesame library?

Tags: sparql, sesame, blazegraph, openrdf

I am working on a project that primarily uses Blazegraph as a back-end, and from what I understand, that locks me into a relatively old Sesame (2.7.12).

The project has another component that can use an embedded Sesame, or a free-standing Sesame OR RDF4J.  **I have a free-standing RDF4J already set up, so I'd prefer to use that.**

I can connect to the embedded Sesame with the following Scala code.  If I change `serverUrl` to point to the free-standing RDF4J 2.2, I get the error below.

Is it possible to access RDF4J servers with the Sesame API?

```
val serverUrl = "http://address.domain:8080/rdf4j-server"
val manager = new RemoteRepositoryManager(serverUrl)
manager.initialize()
val repositoryId = "repo_id"
val repository = manager.getRepository(repositoryId)
val con = repository.getConnection()
val queryString = "SELECT ?x ?y WHERE { ?x ?p ?y } "
val tupleQuery = con.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, queryString)
val result = tupleQuery.evaluate()
```

> [main] WARN org.openrdf.http.client.SesameSession - Server reports
>   problem:
>   org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.config.RepositoryConfigException:
>   Repository implementation for repository missing Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   UuidRefresh.main(UuidRefresh.scala) Caused by:
>   org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPQueryEvaluationException:
>   org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.config.RepositoryConfigException:
>   Repository implementation for repository missing  at
>   org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPTupleQuery.evaluate(HTTPTupleQuery.java:64)
>     at UuidRefresh$.(UuidRefresh.scala:54)    at
>   UuidRefresh$.(UuidRefresh.scala)  ... 1 more Caused by:
>   org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryException:
>   org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.config.RepositoryConfigException:
>   Repository implementation for repository missing  at
>   org.openrdf.http.client.SparqlSession.execute(SparqlSession.java:1100)
>     at
>   org.openrdf.http.client.SparqlSession.executeOK(SparqlSession.java:1028)
>     at
>   org.openrdf.http.client.SparqlSession.sendTupleQueryViaHttp(SparqlSession.java:807)
>     at
>   org.openrdf.http.client.SparqlSession.getBackgroundTupleQueryResult(SparqlSession.java:704)
>     at
>   org.openrdf.http.client.SparqlSession.sendTupleQuery(SparqlSession.java:363)
>     at
>   org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPTupleQuery.evaluate(HTTPTupleQuery.java:58)
>     ... 3 more

Comment: Not helpful and you probably already know that RDF4J is the successor of Sesame?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should have said I already knew that.  But thanks for brainstorming.

Comment: Hm, is it related to this https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues/819? The ticket wasclosed 28 days ago - maybe the latest version of RDF4J (2.2.2) or a SNAPSHOT version will fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure you would be able to access an RDF4J remote repository *as a Sesame HTTPRepository*, especially when your client library is that old. Sesame version 2.7 is quite ancient and a lot of improvements have been done to the REST API since then - they *should* be backwards compatible, but...

However, given that an RDF4J repository running on RDF4J Server is a SPARQL endpoint, you can of course always access it as you would any SPARQL endpoint, by creating a `SPARQLRepository` object.

As an aside: do let the Blazegraph folks know that you'd like to upgrade to RDF4J. Them prioritizing RDF4J support is governed by user demand (as it should be), so let them know it's important to you!